# Why can we create a template class struct with a number of parameters different from those specified when declaring a struct?

Tags: c++

I saw this piece of code somewhere on the Internet, could you tell me why it can be compiled?
As far as I know, if you specified incorrect count of params in template - There should be a compilation error, isn't it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
template<typename F, typename Tuple, bool Enough, int TotalArgs, int... N>
struct call_impl
{
    auto static call(F f, Tuple&& t)
    {
        //This line
        return call_impl<F, Tuple, TotalArgs == 1 + sizeof...(N),
            TotalArgs, N..., sizeof...(N)>::call(f, std::forward<Tuple>(t));
    }
};

template<typename F, typename Tuple, int TotalArgs, int... N>
struct call_impl<F, Tuple, true, TotalArgs, N...>
{
    auto static call(F f, Tuple&& t)
    {
        return f(std::get<N>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
    }
};

template<typename F, typename Tuple>
auto call(F f, Tuple&& t)
{
    typedef typename std::decay<Tuple>::type type;
    return call_impl<F, Tuple, 0 == std::tuple_size<type>::value,
        std::tuple_size<type>::value
    >::call(f, std::forward<Tuple>(t));
}

int foo(int i, double d)
{
    std::cout << "foo: " << i << " " << d << std::endl;
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    std::tuple<int, double> t1(1, 2.3);
    std::cout << call(foo, t1) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Um, that code _doesn't_ compile. Did you try it?

Comment: Is there another `test` template that takes three parameters?

Comment: @NeilButterworth, yes, I tried to compile it in VS. What compiler did you use to compile it (If you tried, of course)?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm no, only one.

Comment: If you have a code containing this snippet that compiles please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This actually does not compile in Visual Studio. It appears to because the compiler doesn't check until you try to use it. so try putting this in a function somewhere, `test<int, 0>::f(0);` to actually get it to try to compile test::f and then actually build because intellisense does not catch it either. you should get a compilation error at this point.

Comment: To clarify... the compiler ignores the function `f` unless the template is used somewhere else in the code, since it ignores the template if it's unused. The function `f` is cleverly designed to fool you because it declares a version of the template. But in reality `f` never exists until some other code uses the template.

Comment: @ChrisRollins I made a mistake when I provided non-informative example. Sorry for that. Now I fixed it.

Comment: In your updated example, the only template used is the std::tuple. The unused templates are ignored by the compiler unless you use them.

Comment: My point is this: If you have a template and you think it shouldn't compile, create an instance of it in main (a function you know for sure is included in compilation) and you will see whether the template has errors or not. If you do not use the template, it is irrelevant, because it is ignored. Think of it like a macro. If a macro has code which should error, it will not trigger an error unless it is used. Templates behave this way as well.

Comment: Thank you for explain, Chris

Answer (score 0):

This [compiles fine](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7xFJU8), if you add the missing includes `#include <iostream>` and 
`#include <tuple>`.

Comment: Note that godbolt shows which lines are included in the compilation. The line the asker is concerned about isn't included.